# finding derivative of geometric series

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How is $\sum_{k=0}^n k.2^k = (2n-2)2^n + 2$

Can someone please explain me the break down?

$k.\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k$ is the sum ok geometric series so

$k.\sum_{k=0}^n 2^k = \frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2}$

Suppose we take x=2 then we can find the derivative 
$k.\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2}$

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2} = 2.x^{n+1} -n.x^n - n.x^{n+1}-x^n -1$

Plugging back 2 in place of x i am not getting $(2n-2)2^n + 2$

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: That makes no sense at all. You have to take the derivative with respect to $x$ *before* you let $x=2$...

Comment: Another nonsensical thing is taking $k$ out of the sum. You can't just split terms apart and move one outside the sum (whence the variable doesn't even exist). $k\sum_{k=0}^n2^k$ is basically meaningless due to how it was derived.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use that

$$\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=0}^n x^k=\sum_{k=0}^n kx^{k-1}=\frac1x\sum_{k=0}^n kx^{k}$$

and

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}=\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}(1-x)+(1-x^{n+1})}{(1-x)^2}$$

and for $x=2$ we obtain

$$\sum_{k=0}^n k2^{k}=2\frac{-(n+1)2^{n}(1-2)+(1-2^{n+1})}{(1-2)^2}=$$

$$=2(n2^n+2^n+1-2^{n+1})=2(n2^n+2^n(1-2)+1)=$$

$$=2(n2^n-2^n+1)=2^n(2n-2)+1$$

Answer (score 2):

When you say "take x=2", you should replace 2 with x. So you need to calculate $$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$
Once you finished calculations in terms of $x$, you can go back and say $x=2$.

Otherwise you have an expression that does not depend on $x$. So when you take the derivative with respect to $x$ you will get $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You evaluate the series in terms of $x$ and then differentiate since $\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1-2^{n+1}}{1-2}\right)=0$.

We have the geometric series for the first $n$ terms $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{k}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$ and differentiating gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}kx^{k-1}=\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}(1-x)+(1-x^{n+1})}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{-(n+1)x^n+nx^{n+1}+1}{(x-1)^2}$$

However, note that we want $\sum_{k=0}^{n}kx^{\color{red}{k}}$ so multiplying by $x$ we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}kx^{k}=\frac{-(n+1)x^{n+1}+nx^{n+2}+x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Now set $x=2$.